# android how to scan or take picture using camera and store that pic in our app

Tags: android

how to use camera in app and store the taken  pic in the app..it i  referred many tutorials but i didnt get the proper code..please help me to solve the problem.My code will ask for save option...and when we reopen the app the picture is not saved neither in app nor in gallery....Please help to do that ..my code is...In this code the captured image is stored in that image view...for once

```
  this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    }) ;
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to save bitmap to storage. The **imageMainDirectory** would look like **"/MyApp/"**. The **imageDirectory** would look like **"/MyApp/MyImages/"**

```
 public boolean saveBitmapToStorage(Bitmap bitmap, String imageMainDirectory,
                                       String imageDirectory, String fileName) {
        boolean result = false;
        // This is true if the saving of image to the external storage fails.
        // Then we proceed to the internal storage
        boolean proceedToInternal;

        // You need to check if External Storage is writable/readable
        if (MemoryManager.isExternalStorageWritable()
                && MemoryManager.isExternalStorageReadable()) {
        // Check if Memory is equals or greater than 10mb
            if (MemoryManager.checkSdCardMemory(10)) {
                File imgdir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + imageDirectory);
                File file = new File(imgdir, fileName);
                // (Optional) replace file if its already existing
                if (file.exists()) file.delete();
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    result = true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                proceedToInternal = false;
            } else {
                proceedToInternal = true;
            }
        } else {
            proceedToInternal = true;
        }
        if (proceedToInternal) {
            if (MemoryManager.checkInternalMemory(10)) {
                File imgdir = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()
                        + imageDirectory);
                File file = new File(imgdir, fileName);
                // (Optional) replace file if its already existing
                if (file.exists()) file.delete();
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    result = true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Here is the Memory Manager class:

```
public class MemoryManager {

   public static boolean checkSdCardMemory(long desiredMemory) {
      boolean result = true;

      StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getPath());
      long bytesAvailable = (long) stat.getBlockSize()
            * (long) stat.getAvailableBlocks();
      long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / 1048576;

      if (megAvailable < desiredMemory) {
         result = false;
      }

      return result;
   }

   public static boolean checkInternalMemory(long desiredMemory) {
      boolean result = true;

      StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
      long bytesAvailable = (long) stat.getBlockSize()
            * (long) stat.getAvailableBlocks();
      long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / 1048576;

      if (megAvailable < desiredMemory) {
         result = false;
      }

      return result;
   }

   public static boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
      String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
      if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }

   /* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
   public static boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
      String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
      if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)
            || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you...shouldni insert all the code in my main class

Comment: isExternalStorageReadable()  .createDIRNoMediaFile cnnot resolve method :error